# Fetching part of SQL query for a WHILE loop on php

Tags: php, sql

Trying to fetch part of the query for a while loop.
I have an INNER JOIN sql query using four tables.
On the first while i'm fetching the orders AKA mod_orders
On the second loop i'm trying to fetch the order products with the information from the other tables AKA mod_orders_pords (pords intended).

so my first while needs to use only SELECT * FROM mod_orders
and the second while needs to loop the rest without the grouping part.

**The question is: how do i run the second while?**

```
SELECT * FROM mod_orders AS mo
                                            INNER JOIN mod_orders_pords AS mop
                                            ON mo.`id` = mop.`order_id`
                                            INNER JOIN mod_products_list AS mpl
                                            ON mop.`prod_id` = mpl.`id`
                                            INNER JOIN mod_products AS mp
                                            ON mpl.`id` = mp.`page_id`
                                            GROUP BY  mop.`order_id`
                                            ORDER BY mo.`id` DESC
```

Comment: What's the question? Please edit your post and add in the relevant code.

Comment: I'v edit the question.

Comment: Sorry - but I only see a single query. You keep mentioning _while loop_ but you haven't shown one at all. Please show us your PHP code too.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear and doesn't specify the issue. I think you need to group all orders with product and product info.

First it is better to avoid * specially if you will access the row using the field name as all tables have id field.

You have order -> orderProduct -> product, so you need to sort by order_id then product id.

Then you will create one while loop and start building your array of objects, see sample code as example.

```
<?php
//I assume the you have result object using your sql query 
$order = new stdClass();
$data = array(); //this array will contains all orders
$order->id = null;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if(is_null($order->id) || $order->id != $row['order_id'])
    {
        //this means that we need to create new order->object
        $order = new stdClass();
        $order->$row['order_id'];
        // add more data like order value etc..
        $order->products = array();
        $data[] = &$order; //add order by refrence
        unset($product);
        $product = new stdClass();
        $product->id =null;
    }
    if(is_null($product->id) || $product->id != $row['product_id']){
        unset($product);
        $product = new stdClass();
        $product->id = $row['product_id'];
        // add more data like product name etc..
        $order->products[] = &$product;
    }
}
// unset all objects
unset($order, $product);
```

using this code you can achieve what you need but remember to sort by order, so first sort by order_id then sort by product_id. `order by order_id, product_id`. If you have third level added to the order by statement and no need to use group by is this case.